# One-row subgrids not expanding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a grid where each row has a subgrid.

It seems that when a subgrid has multiple rows, it is expandable. But when it has only one row, it is not expandable.

How can a row that contains a one-row subgrid be made to be expandable?

I am using the "grid as a sub-grid" method for displaying subgrids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a special character "$" in the sub-grid's ID.